# Simple todo application

Tags: javascript, jquery, to-do-list

I have been learning HTML/JavaScript and CSS. I have gone through some of the online tutorials, PDFs and books as well. Though, now I am familiar with syntactical stuff, I wasn't sure how I should design or structure code, so I started with a small ToDo application. I didn't want to use any frameworks. As I am still learning, I thought I should spend sometime learning the basics before using any frameworks.

[GitHub](https://github.com/chandravellanki/GitHubRepo/tree/4eee76eed4e283cfdccf4b6b478cb8ac3ecbbe10)

```
{
(function (){

    //Create a modal, which contains an array to hold list of todos
    var modal = {
        init: function () {
            this.todolist = [];
            this.todolist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tododata"));
            if (this.todolist === null)
                this.todolist = [];
        },
        getTodoList: function () {
            return this.todolist;
        },
        setTodoState: function (intodoid) {
            //Set status
            this.todolist[intodoid].status === "closed" ?
                this.todolist[intodoid].status = "open" : this.todolist[intodoid].status = "closed";
            localStorage.setItem("tododata", JSON.stringify(this.todolist));
        },
        setNewTodo: function (inval) {
            this.todolist.push({
                id: this.todolist.length,
                name: inval,
                status: "open"
            });
            localStorage.setItem("tododata", JSON.stringify(this.todolist));
            this.myFirebaseRef.push({id: this.todolist.length, name: inval, status: "open"});
        },
        clearall: function () {
            this.todolist = [];
        }
    }

    //Create a View, which interacts with Controller and alters the display in HTML
    var view = {
        init: function () {
            this.todolst = $('#todolistelm');
            this.todolst.html(' ');
            view.render();
            $('#clearall').click(function () {
                localStorage.clear();
                controller.clearall();
                view.render();
            });
        },
        render: function () {
            var htmlStr = '';
            var clr = true;
            var todoelem = $('#todolistelm');
            todoelem.html('');

            if (controller.getTodoList().length === 0) {
                $("#cleanmsg").css("visibility", "visible");
                $("#displaysection").css("visibility", "hidden")
            } else {
                $("#cleanmsg").css("visibility", "hidden");
                $("#displaysection").css("visibility", "visible")
            }

            controller.getTodoList().forEach(function (todo) {
                //DOM elements

                var elemId = ' ';
                var lielem = $('<li></li>');
                var spanelem = $('<span></span>');
                var taskid = "#task" + todo.id;

                //Create <li> element and add required classes
                lielem.addClass("list-group-item");
                //Set status of the todo item
                todo.status === "closed" ? lielem.addClass("completed") : lielem.addClass("");
                //Set alternate color
                clr === true ? lielem.addClass("colored") : lielem.addClass("");
                clr = !clr;

                //Create <span> and add required classes and IDs
                spanelem.addClass("glyphicon");
                spanelem.addClass("glyphicon-ok pull-right");
                spanelem.addClass("todocomplete");
                spanelem.attr('id', "task" + todo.id);

                //Append span and name to <li>
                lielem.append(spanelem);
                lielem.append(todo.name);

                //Append <li> to main list
                $(todoelem).append(lielem);

                //Add event handlers
                $(taskid).click(function (todoid) {
                    return function () {
                        controller.setTodoState(todoid);
                        view.render();
                    };
                }(todo.id));
            });

            //Set focus on input textbox by default
            $('#intodo').focus();
        }
    };

    //Create a controller, which acts as a mediator between View and Modal
    var controller = {
        init: function () {
            //Initialize view and modal
            modal.init();
            view.init();
        },
        getTodoList: function () {
            return modal.getTodoList();
        },
        setTodoState: function (intodoid) {
            modal.setTodoState(intodoid);
        },
        setNewTodo: function (inval) {
            modal.setNewTodo(inval);
        },
        clearall: function () {
            modal.clearall();
        }
    };

    //Set ENTER key on the input text box
    $('#intodo').keypress(function (e) {
        if (((e.which && e.which == 13) ||
                (e.keyCode && e.KeyCode == 13)) &&
            $("#intodo").val().trim().length > 0) {
            controller.setNewTodo($("#intodo").val());
            view.render();
            $("#intodo").val('');
        }
    });

    //Set the controller to start the work
    controller.init();
})();
}
```

Can someone go through this code and let me know if this follows the best practices or not, as well as any areas that I should probably be focusing on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick once over:

- Your first line creates an anonymous function, it offers you the opportunity to pick a great function name that conveys to the reader what he is about to be exposed to like `(function todoApp(){`
- This

  ```
  init: function () {
      this.todolist = [];
      this.todolist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tododata"));
      if (this.todolist === null)
          this.todolist = [];
  },
  ```

  could be

  ```
  init: function () {
      this.todolist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tododata")) || [];
  }
  ```

  essentially you were overwriting `this.todolist = []` with
   `this.todolist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tododata"));`
  furthermore [you should never drop the curly braces after an `if` block](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/)
- You are copy pasting this line of code all over the place, you should have a dedicated function for this:
  `localStorage.setItem("tododata", JSON.stringify(this.todolist));`
- This:

  ```
  setTodoState: function (intodoid) {
      //Set status
      this.todolist[intodoid].status === "closed" ?
          this.todolist[intodoid].status = "open" : this.todolist[intodoid].status = "closed";
      localStorage.setItem("tododata", JSON.stringify(this.todolist));
  },
  ```

  has a few problems, `intodoid` is an unfortunate name because it is not lowerCamelCase and because it smells like Hungarian notation. Also the repetition of `this.todolist[intodoid].status` is too much. I would suggest something like this:

  ```
  toggleTodoState: function (todoId) {
      //Toggle status
      var status = this.todolist[todoId].status;
      this.todolist[todoId].status = status == "closed" ? "open" : "closed";
      updateTodoData();
  },
  ```